# Column names of xlsx file are not retained in the converted csvs

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, xlsx

I am fetching data from a multisheet xlsx file and storing data in separate csv files. The first rows of all the sheets in xslx are stored in the first csv, the 2nd rows of all the sheets are stored in the 2nd csv, and, so on. For that I wrote the following code which works:

```
xls = xlrd.open_workbook(r'Smallys ORDER.xlsx', on_demand=True)
df_list = []

names = xls.sheet_names()
#print(names)
#print('-'*80)
names.remove('EVENT')
#print(names)

for i in range(191):
    rows = []
    for name in names:
        count = 0
        prod = pd.read_excel('Smallys ORDER.xlsx', name, index_col=None)
        #print(prod)
        try:
            item = prod.iloc[i]
            print(item)
            rows.append(item)
            #items = item.concat(item)
            #print(items)
            #prod.to_csv(item + '.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False) 
            #print('-'*80)

        except:
            print('Row finished !!!')


    writer = csv.writer(open('/home/hp/products/' + 'prod['+str(i)+'].csv', 'w'))  
    writer.writerows(rows)
```

**This code does not retain the column names of the xlsx file (same for all the sheets) in the csvs.**

Comment: You cannot have sheet names in a csv

Comment: there aren't sheet names in the .csv - that writer is inside the range and each .csv is a different set of rows.

Comment: Not sheet name but column names.

Comment: I'd add a "print(rows)" right before the writer = line to clarify what's happening

Comment: Do all sheets share the same column names? If yes, it is enough to write the headers of the first sheet

Comment: @SergeBallesta : yes, they do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to explicitely write the column names when you use a `csv.writer`. It is enough to use the column names from the last sheet:

```
writer = csv.writer(open('/home/hp/products/' + 'prod['+str(i)+'].csv', 'w'))
writer.writerow(prod.columns.tolist())
writer.writerows(rows)
```